# cppFunction: Compiling Rcout << "line break\n"

Tags: r, rcpp

Why does a Rcpp function with a `\n` line break sent to `Rcpp::Rcout` not compile?

This works

```
cppFunction('void testing() {Rcout<<"hello"<<std::endl;}')
testing()
# hello
```

but this doesn't

```
cppFunction('void testing() {Rcout<<"hello\n";}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R's string escaping is getting in your way. Try:

```
cppFunction('void testing() {Rcout<<"hello\\n";}')
```

Note the double `\\`. Rather than transferring a literal new-line to the generated C++ script, you want to send the characters `\n` themselves -- hence, you need to escape the `\`.

To avoid issues like this, you should prefer using the attributes interface -- see [Rcpp-attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).

Note that this error becomes more obvious if you try running `cppFunction('void testing() {Rcout<<"hello\n";}', verbose=TRUE)` -- you can see the generated script has a literal newline rather than the `\n` characters.